# Can't change terminal size on pty/N (works on ttyN)

Tags: terminal, ioctl, tty, pty

I use the next to change terminal size:

`rc = ioctl(fd, TIOCSWINSZ, &ws);`

When I run this under linux text terminal (switching by Alt-Ctrl-F1), the result is that I expect to see. The whole my input and output within ranges given by ioctl syscall.
But when I connect to localhost by SSH, and run the same program, it works only partly. I mean that I can't input command wider than terminal size set by ioctl, but the output can cross the borders of terminal given by ioctl, and input can take more rows that set by ioctl. Also there is no auto carriage return and new line after that.
The only difference that I see when I run program directly it run on the terminal /dev/ttyN, and it's major number is 5, and when I run program via SSH it use /dev/pts/N as terminal, with major number 136.
So, as I understood, it happens due the difference in terminals.
My questions:
1. Is that correct? Is the reason in terminal drivers?
2. How do I fix it? I need the same behaviour via SSH like in local tty terminal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually `TIOCSWINSZ` is used by the tty master (such as `xterm`, the Linux console itself, etc...) to tell the kernel driver how big the terminal actually is. The program running on the tty slave (i.e. the application itself) uses `TIOCGWINSZ` to query the size of the terminal. Most tty drivers don't support pushing it the other way; you can't in general call `TIOCSWINSZ` on the tty slave from the application and get the master to change its size.

Some terminals, such as `xterm` do support escape sequences to request them to resize, but this is just a byte escape sequence, and not an `ioctl()` command.

If you want the application to force the size of the terminal, then portably there is no way to do this. Unportably, you can apply a few special tricks like attempting `TIOCSWINSZ` or sending the `xterm` escape sequence.

Comment: So, returning to my questions:
1. Generally yes. The reason in drivers. Because not all drivers allow to push size from slave terminal to master.
2. No portably way. I can try to use ioctl and escape sequences.
Correct? Thank you!

Comment: My experience (a few minutes prior to this comment) is that xterm does not support the vt100 "<esc>[8;<h>;<w>t" escape sequence, but gnome-terminal does.  So generally, this doesn't seem to be a feature that you can rely upon as working.